# Assign variable value to a form field in a template

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms, django-templates

I wish to assign a value from  variable `word` in my view function `one_label` to the form field `label` in my template. I've seen some solutions with javascript but I'm not sure how to use them with the form field in the template?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var myVar = "{{someDjangoVariable}}"
</script>
```

in models

```
class Labels(models.Model):
   label = models.CharField()
```

in forms

```
class LabelForm(forms.Form):

 label = forms.CharField(required = False)
```

in views

```
def one_label(request, postID):
   one_label = Labels.objects.get(id=postID
   if request.method =='POST':
      form = LabelForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():


         word = "something"
      else:
        form = LabelForm()
      c = {"form"=form, "one_label"=one_label, "word"=word  }
      c.update(csrf(request))
      render(response,'mytemplate.html', c)
```

in template

```
 <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

      {{ form.as_p}}

  # assign value in var "word" in views to form field "label"

 # something like    {{ form.label}}:{{ word}}

 </form>
```

Comment: Is `{{ word }}` something that comes from the views context or something else?

Comment: its value comes from a separate python function that's called in the view function one_label

Answer (score 2):

First, there is a syntax error in your `views.py`, at least, or this is a syntax totally unknown to me. Context is a Python dictionary that could be declared as:

```
c = {'form': form, 'one_label': one_label, 'word': word}
```

I would strongly recommend you to get a grip on a good IDE, it will very much help you with syntax.

Regarding the form rendering, I would then recommend you to expand the form field rendering by replacing `{{ form }}` with something like:

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.label.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.label.id_for_label }}">{{ word }}</label>
    {{ form.label }}
</div>
```

See also [Django documentation: Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

About assigning a value within a template, you could use the [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag although it seems kind of irrelevant to me  for your particular problem.